# Multiple login in Shiro

Tags: authentication, shiro, multiple-login

shiro multiple login

I have a web app which have 2 parts: front part and backend part. Both part need a login page for users. 
Members need to use /signin to login front part. 
Admins need to use /admin/signin to login backend part.

```
public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter(WebSecurityManager securityManager){
    ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
    shiroFilter.setSecurityManager(securityManager);

    Map<String, Filter> filterMap = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
    FormAuthenticationFilter adminAuthc = new FormAuthenticationFilter();
    adminAuthc.setLoginUrl("/admin/signin");
    adminAuthc.setSuccessUrl("/admin/course");
    filterMap.put("adminAuthc", adminAuthc);
    FormAuthenticationFilter authc = new FormAuthenticationFilter();
    adminAuthc.setLoginUrl("/signin");
    adminAuthc.setSuccessUrl("/");
    filterMap.put("authc", authc);
    shiroFilter.setFilters(filterMap);

    Map<String, String> filterChainDefinitionMap = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/signout", "logout");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/style/**", "anon");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/javascript/**", "anon");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/image/**", "anon");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/flash/**", "anon");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/favicon.ico", "anon");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/captcha/**", "anon");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/course", "anon");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/course/**", "anon");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/course/*/collect", "authc");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/course/*/uncollect", "authc");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/course/study/record", "authc");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/**", "authc");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/admin/**", "adminAuthc");
    shiroFilter.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChainDefinitionMap);

    return shiroFilter;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Explain what the problem is and things you've tried.